# How to display MBs in KBs in Chrome Devtools Network panel?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, bundle

Current Network Devtools tab displays MBs:

[image]

Is there some settings to display MBs in KBs and in full number, not decimal (33.5 as 33500)? Need to know precise value (e.g. 33.5 => 33527)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to change the unit used by the Size column, but you can do one of the following:

- download the file and inspect its size locally
- add a column for a 'Content-Length' response header
  [image: content-length header column in Chrome DevTools Network panel]

As you can see on the screenshot it's not perfect though - it's provided by the server and it's not required.

- export entry as a HAR file and look up the exact value
  [image: example HAR file export]
- use the Resource Timing API to list all resources in the console
  [image]

(see [Possible to list external resources loaded on a webpage with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157012/possible-to-list-external-resources-loaded-on-a-webpage-with-javascript) )