# Checking website resources with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way using injected javascript to view the loaded resources of a website? For example, on Reddit, if I look at the resources tab, it has a folder for recently visited subreddits. I want to check if a specific folder exists as a resource on the page. Is this possible?

Here is what the Chrome DevTools Sources tab looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this old answer can help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157267/11368483

this code give you a list of all external resources included in the page

```
var resources = window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
resources.forEach(function (resource) {
    console.log(resource.name);
});
```

Inside the forEach loop you can test the resource name like in this edited example:

```
var resources = window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
resources.forEach(function (resource) {
    if (resource.name.includes("/yourfoldername/"){
     // DO WHAT YOU WANT IF YOUR FOLDER EXIST
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to get the filenames as you would think it does. For some reason, resource.name returns a URL rather than a file path.